# Doing digital IoT and some analog circuits without an oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, switching-regulator, hobbyist, iot

In my free time, I do electronic stuff as a hobby (at least for now.) I don't own an oscilloscope or a fancy multimeter due to the terrible financial state of my country.  I am in Iran.

In some situations, like building a power supply circuit for my projects, or working with circuits that involve switching stuff with MOSFETs, etc., I need know how much noise is being generated.  Even being able to measure peak to peak voltage difference would help me to know if the circuit is usable or not.

How can I get around this without an oscilloscope? Dummy oscilloscope kits are not an option.  They are not trustable and too fragile. If there are any good ones, they are not accessible here.

Comment: An old oscilloscope would still be very useful.

Comment: Yeah, but surprisingly the prices are not that different. I guess that's because of high demand :shrug:

Comment: Those little 2" screen scope kits from you-know-where are not high performance and fiddly to use, but they are certainly better than nothing. If I was in your place I'd consider fitting one with proper switches, a PSU and input protection.

Comment: "Old" can mean **really** old.  I use a Telequipment D43 dual trace analog oscilloscope that was manufactured in 1965.  People use their scopes to make (or try to make) precise measurements, but often times all you need is a general look at things.  If your linear voltage regulator is oscillating, you don't care at what frequency or how many volts peak to peak - it shouldn't oscillate at all, so just seeing that it oscillates is information enough to fix the problem.

Comment: @JRE I know. They are pretty rare nowadays(at least here) and finding one that works is virtually impossible.

Comment: Would USB oscilloscopes work for you?

Comment: @Justme The prices are not that different from a low-end model of a benchtop Rigol oscilloscope. There are affordable ones(like some cheap models of Hantek) but I don't think they are worth it.

Comment: https://github.com/fhdm-dev/scoppy

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can stick to the recommended components (pay particular attention to inductors) for things like switching power supplies. It's going to be pretty difficult to do original design and debugging without a real oscilloscope. Of course simulators are free. You can get some idea of ripple with a voltmeter on AC range if you know the frequency response of the meter, how it measures (eg. fake RMS from average for many cheap meters) and the ripple frequency.

A decent new name-brand (eg. Rigol) starter 2-channel 100MHz oscilloscope is around $300. USD, at least here in Canada. I would stay 100% away from the junk kit things.

For logic, an inexpensive (like $10 USD) logic analyzer with open-source software (eg. Sigrok) is pretty good, but not sure if you can easily order it from your country.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I have tried sticking to the recommended parts in datasheets but I think I ended up with a lot of noise. I tried to filter it with common solutions but I have no idea if it worked. Rigol is a pretty good choice but out of budget(1$ = 271400 IRR, Monthly gross income in the order of 500$).

Comment: Hantek has  not expensive devices. You can buy on Ali direct from manufacturer

Comment: @user263983 the cheapest Hantek benchtop costs around 230$ and if I wanted to spend that much, I'd rather buy a Rigol instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a computer with a sound card (including a microphone input) then you can use that along with some freely downloadable software to make an oscilloscope. Different sound cards are capable of different sample rates, but none of them can approach the sample rate of even the least expensive Rigol or Hantek.

One example is [here](https://makezine.com/projects/sound-card-oscilloscope).